# how to dynamic data display on scrolling with webdis and redis

Tags: ajax, jquery, web-applications, nosql, redis

I am currently trying to display the data from redis in a webpage using webdis to connect to redis, since i have like 300000+ data and it can grow even larger, i want to display the data only on scrolling to make it load fast, I know how we can do this in the my-sql by using the identity but the data which is present in the redis is like "1.2.3.4,11.22.33.44". How can i possible display data on scroll ?

currently I am using something like this

```
<script>
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc()
{ 
url = "http://127.0.0.1:7379/zrangebyscore/key_name/-inf/+inf"; 
xmlhttp=null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for all new browsers
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{// code for IE5 and IE6
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (xmlhttp!=null)
{
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else
{
alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
}
}

function state_Change()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{// 4 = "loaded"
if (xmlhttp.status==200)
{// 200 = OK
//alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
//alert(jsonData.zrangebyscore.length);

document.write('<center><table>');
//loop for rows 
for(var i=0;i < jsonData.zrangebyscore.length;i++)
{ 
document.write('<tr>'); 
document.write('<td>' + i + ']</td>'); 
document.write('<td>' + jsonData.zrangebyscore[i] + '</td>');
document.write('</tr>'); 
}
document.write('</table></center>');

}
else
{
alert("Problem retrieving data");
}
}
}
</script>
```

which will at-least takes 2-3 mins to display the full data